# Add minutes where we have same datetime in list<DateTime>

Tags: c#, list, linq, datetime

I have the following list:

```
List<DateTime> list =
    new [] { "12:00", "12:00", "12:00", "12:30", "12:30", "14:00" }
        .Select(DateTime.Parse)
        .ToList();
```

I need some function which can make this list in this way:

```
{ 12:00, 12:01, 12:02, 12:30, 12:31, 14:00 }
```

So, if there are the same `DateTime` I should increase minutes by 1 for each one.

Comment: You'd need some sort of loop and save somewhere the last duplicate found. Anything you've tried so far?

Comment: Is your list always sorted in ascending order? If not, what would be the result if your values would be `{12:00, 12:01, 12:00}`? Does the second `12:00` becomes `12:01` or `12:02`?

Comment: My list always sorted in ascending order

Comment: What should be the output for `{12:00, 12:00, 12:01}`?

Comment: {12:00, 12:01, 12:02}

Comment: What should {12:00, 12:01, 12:00} result in ?

Comment: Do you just want unique times, are they always ordered, does order matter,  you need to be specific

Comment: for  {12:00, 12:01, 12:00} it should give {12:00, 12:01, 12:02}

Comment: are they always ordered ? or can it be in any order

Comment: Yes the list is always ordered initially

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `times` is sorted in ascending order, this should work:

```
private static IEnumerable<DateTime> NewTimes(IEnumerable<DateTime> times)
{
    var current = DateTime.MinValue;
    foreach (var time in times)
    {
        if (time > current) current = time;
        yield return current;
        current = current.AddMinutes(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this looks right (considering all the new information) +1

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ and do it like this (assuming your timestamps are of type `DateTime`)

```
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> MakeUnique(IEnumerable<DateTime> timestamps)
    {
        return timestamps.GroupBy(t => t).SelectMany(g => g.Select((t, i) => t.AddMinutes(i)));
    }
```

It works by first grouping your timestamps into groups that have the same timestamp. Then for each group it looks at the group as a list and adds x number of minutes where x is the index in the list. So the first one gets 0 minutes added, the second gets 1 minute added and so on. Then it uses SelectMany to flatten the smaller lists back into a single list.

Comment: would this result in something like 12:00, 12:00... 30 times and then 12:30 producing 12:00,12:01...12:29, 12:30, 12:30 though?

Comment: Yes it would. It works as long as the results in one group don't overlap the results of another group. So it works for OP's original example but not for some of the ones in the comments.

Comment: It won't work for something like 12:00, 12:00, 12:01. Then it would return 12:00, 12:01, 12:01 since it would make 2 groups and 12:01 would be in the output of both groups.

Comment: yes, you are right, do you have any suggestions for that kind of situation?

Comment: To solve that issue, I did it the same way as Peter

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy to NuGet "System.Interactive" to get the `Scan` extension method for enumerables, then this also works:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> output =
    list
        .Scan((a, x) => x > a ? x : a.AddMinutes(1.0))
        .StartWith(list.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the job with `.Aggregate`:

```
List<DateTime> list =
    new [] { "12:00", "12:00", "12:00", "12:30", "12:30", "14:00" }
        .Select(DateTime.Parse)
        .ToList();

List<DateTime> output =
    list.Skip(1).Aggregate(list.Take(1).ToList(), (a, x) =>
    {
        a.Add(a.Last() >= x ? a.Last().AddMinutes(1.0): x);
        return a;
    });
```

That gives me:

```
{ 12:00, 12:01, 12:02, 12:30, 12:31, 14:00 }
```